# Get all classes and add to new element

Tags: jquery

I have several classes that I want to dynamically add to a new div.

**Sample HTML**

```
<span class="class1 class2 class3">
```

**JS**

```
var theClass = $("span").attr('class');
$("span").replaceWith( "<div class=" + theClass + ">");
```

**Problem**

This gets all the classes but wraps the first one only in quotes.

```
<div class="class1" class2 class3>
```

**Question**

How do I make it so all three classes are wrapped in the quotes?

`<div class="class1 class2 class3"`>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code was close to being functional, you just left the quotes off around your `class` attribute value.

```
var theClass = $("span").attr('class');
$("span").replaceWith( "<div class='" + theClass + "'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps,

```
var theClass = $("span").attr('class');
$("span").replaceWith("<div>").addClass(theClass);
```